# datepicker date format little issue

Tags: datepicker

I put a new datepicker into a admin page and it lets me select the date needed but when I had data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd" as dd/mm/yyyy, it would not save the date in the database and would save it as 0000-00-00 so I changed the format to data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd" and it works now and saves the date correctly now in the database but is there any way I can have the date format as dd/mm/yyyy in the input field as it currently shows as 2019/10/22

The code I have is below

```
<div id="exstdate" class="col-lg-6 input-group date" data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="exstdate" value="<?php echo $exstdate; ?>" id="exstdate" readonly />
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span><div class="error alert-danger"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
$("#exstdate").datepicker({
language: "en",
autoclose: true, 
todayHighlight: true,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
}).datepicker('update', new Date()); 
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What language are you using? Put that in the tags, please.

Comment: Sorry I added the language in the javascript code